# Cursor coordinates in ArcGIS Online

Tags: coordinates, arcgis-online, widget

I use the coordinate widget in ArcGIS Online. I then get the coordinates when clicking in the map. Is it possible to get the coordinates "real-time" when moving the cursor?

Comment: Are you using web app builder or are you speaking of the map viewer? This help doc allows you to turn on a Location in the new web viewer: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/get-started/find-location-coordinates-mv.htm

Comment: Im using the WebAppBuilder. The doc in the link shows how to turn on/of coordinates, but I would like to get the coordinates change in real time, when moving the mouse in the map (not clicking)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm not understanding you correctly, that should just come standard with the ArcGIS Web AppBuilder. To make sure, I just went into my ArcGIS Online account and created an app under the My Content tab. From within the WAB, without even adding any widget, the coordinates are shown in the lower left and are linked to your cursor movement.
[image]

You mention the Coordinates Widget. There is also the Coordinate Conversion Widget.
[image]

It is also available using the [Javascript API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-coordinateconversion/).